# incorrect login linq and datatable

Tags: linq, authentication, datatable

i try to show when i enter incorrect username and password then want to show error message  this is what i try

```
public DataTable loginfunction(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            Entities2 lg = new Entities2();          
            List<SP_GetLogin_Result> gr = lg.SP_GetLogin(username, password).ToList();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            foreach (var l in gr)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(l.id);
            }
            return dt;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }

    }
```

**updated**

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                String strRole = Assignroles(txt_us.Text);
                FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txt_us.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, strRole, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));
                loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
            }
            catch
            {
                Label1.Text = ("Incorrect UserName/Password");
                 Label1.Visible = true;
            }
            txt_us.Text = "";
            txt_pwd.Text = "";
        }
```

login method

```
  private bool loginmethod(string UserName, string Password)
    {
         if((txt_us.Text!="NA") && (txt_pwd.Text!= "NA"))
        {
             login_class lg_class = new login_class();
            Entities2 login = new Entities2();
            string logn = Convert.ToString(lg_class.loginfunction(UserName, Password).Rows[0]["id"]);
            Session["ID"] = logn.ToString();
            return (logn);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

  }


    private string Assignroles(string username)
    {
         if ((txt_us.Text !=string.Empty) && (txt_pwd.Text!= string.Empty))
            return "";
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

when i try above code and when i login with wrong username and password then this show error incrrect username and password

but when i enter correct information i.e. username and password then this always show incorrect username and password where as i want to redirect another page when info is correct

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to home just when the user info is correct.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(loginmethod(txt_us.Text,txt_pwd.Text)!="NA")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                    String strRole =Assignroles(txt_us.Text);
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txt_us.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, strRole, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                    FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)));
                    loginmethod(txt_us.Text, txt_pwd.Text);
                    //if data is correct, redirect to home.aspx
                    Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
               }
                else
                {
                  //if the data is not correct the just show message
                  Label1.Text = ("Incorrect UserName/Password");
                    Label1.Visible = true;
                }
                txt_us.Text = "";
                txt_pwd.Text = "";
            }
```

Comment: but label1 control is on login page not on home.aspx

Comment: Then just remove Response.Redirect("home.aspx") from else clause.

Comment: but how i call label1 on login home .aspx when there is no control of label 1

Comment: I don't understand your app flow: you are on login.aspx, if the data is correct then you will redirect the user to home.aspx, else you will show the "Incorrect UserName/Password" message on login.aspx and Label1 is on login.aspx?

Comment: yes label1 is on login.aspx.. when i open login page enter username and password then redirect to home page .. but when information is incorrect then must show message incorrect username and password on login page and label1 is on login.aspx not on home page..